# Setting up React App with Functional Components using Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

How to set up a React Application with Firebase?
Using Functional Components and the Material UI library, implementing hooks retain the auth state.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to develop a simple boilerplate project for React Dashboard with SignUP, SignIN using Firebase. The routes are maintained in App.js file. To ease the process the project consumes React Functional Components along with Hooks - useState, useEffect. This can be really helpful for beginners.

This project is built using Material UI Library. Utilizing the following templates:

1. Dashboard (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/)
2. SignIN (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/)
3. SignUP (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/sign-up/)

This project utilizes different material-ui components like:

1. Date Picker
2. Switch
3. Text Field
4. Select
5. Custom Dialog Reusable Modal
6. Icons

To begin,

1. Pull the repo from Github.
2. Use "npm install" to install all the node dependencies.
3. Update src/Components/firebase.js file with your firebase project credentials.
4. Run "yarn start" or "npm start" to start the project.

You will initially be redirected to SignIN page. Select the option "Don't have an account? SignUp" and you will be redirected to SignUP page. Enter credentials and you will be logged into Dashboard.

Video Demo Link: https://youtu.be/aWUr3GRbhhs

Github Repo: https://github.com/aaygupta/react-dashboard-boilerplate